# how to draw a cursor in glfw while getting mouse input?

Tags: sprite, glfw, mousewheel

I have a program using glfw for window management and opengl for rendering. The program works on Windows and linux, and eventually Mac OSX so I want any solution to be portable.

glfw seems to either support a cursor, or getting full mouse input but not both. For example, with the cursor enabled (default) the glfwscroll_callback does nothing. If I disable the cursor, then scrolling the mouse is captured but then the user cannot see where the mouse pointer is. That's ok if I can draw the cursor myself when I want but I cannot find any function to drawcursor at a particular location.

How does the cursor work, ie what is the hardware basis for the cursor? Is there a sprite in hardware still? If it's all in software, I suppose we could draw a cursor at the current mouse location the last thing in render. But that's not convenient. For one thing if the scene hasn't changed, I shut down rendering completely to reduce power.

Is there any way to manually draw a cursor on top of the current screen so that we don't have to manage the buffers manually? Is my only option to change the logic and not render the scene if nothing has changed, but to manually draw a cursor on top of the current scene every frame?

Comment: The behavior you describe about not getting scroll events when having the cursor active sounds strange. Or at least I can't reproduce it. Scroll events are sent for me no matter if the cursor is active or not. I've tested on Windows 10. Edit: Could it be that you have enabled `GLFW_RAW_MOUSE_MOTION`?

Comment: not sure but it's working now. I'm mystified what happened